# a function to get maximum

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I am new in Haskell.I am trying to do the following:

The given List datatype structure is:`data Lan a = Nan | Can a (Lan a) deriving Show`

And finally I did it!

```
data Lan a = Nan | Can a (Lan a) deriving Show
```

Comment: The last pattern is too specific: it doesn't catch any list that has two or more elements.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "error/not working" ? btw, hint: the last line should probably start with `maxList (Cons x xs) = ` where `xs` matches any list no matter how long it is...

Comment: I'm posting the error exactly.

Comment: @AliToto that error says that `Cons 8` doesn't match the definition of `List` you gave since the `Cons` constructor takes two argument, e.g. `Cons 8 Nil`. A good intro to Haskell lists is http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists

Comment: It looks to me as if the type error is not in the program, but rather in the interactive attempt to test the program. The sample list has not been finished properly with `Nil`. Once that problem has been fixed, the error in the implementation will reveal itself.

Comment: @mb21 I tried this now: maxList Cons x xs = if xs == Nil then x else max x (maxList xs _)

Comment: Error is that `Cons` has two arguments, and in your expression `(Cons 3 (Cons 5 (Cons 8)))` mentioned in error message, specifically in `Cons 8` only one is passed.
Error is not about your `maxList` function implementation.

In different try you have to add braces: `maxList (Cons x y)`

Comment: you're making progress :) the `Equations for maxList have different numbers of arguments` is because `maxList Cons x xs` should be `maxList (Cons x xs)`. btw, you won't need the `if xs == Nil` since you already have the `maxList Nil = `

Comment: @mb21 I did it!

Comment: @AliToto congrats :) btw, the `Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Eq (List a)` was because you used `==` in `xs == Nil`, so you'd have to write `data List ... deriving (Show, Eq)` to generate the `==` function for your data type in addition to the `show` function...

Answer (score 3):

My problem was in understanding pattern matching.I did it finally:

```
data Lan a = Nan | Can a (Lan a) deriving Show
```